# Search for certain UPN suffix

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How do I search AD users by UPN suffix in AD? The users are under `Uofguelph/SEC213/users` OU.

Some users have `@sec213.com` suffix and some have `@home.sec213.com` suffix. I need to search for users who only have `@sec213.com` suffix.

I have the following two code snippets. Code 1 gets all accounts in the users OU. Code 2 gets all accounts ending with that suffix. I couldn't get it to combine the two.

Code 1:

```psh
Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -Like "@sec213.com"} | Ft Name, userprincipalname
```

Code 2:

```psh
Get-ADUser cmdlet
Clear-Host
Get-ADUser -LDAPfilter '(name=)' `
    -SearchBase 'OU=users,OU=sec213,ou=uofguelph,DC=corp,DC=local,DC=com' |
  Ft name, userprincipalname
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share any code you did already with us?

Comment: Hey, extremely sorry for the late reply. Code 1 gets all accounts in the users OU. Code 2 gets all accounts ending with that suffix. I couldnt get it to combine the two.   Code 1: get-aduser -filter {UserPrincipalName -Like "*@sec213.com"} | Ft Name, userprincipalname
Code 2# Get-AdUser cmdlet
Clear-host
Get-ADUser -LDAPfilter '(name=*)' `
-searchBase 'OU=users,OU=sec213,ou=uofguelph,DC=corp,DC=local,DC=com' | Ft name, userprincipalname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`Get-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx) and filter on user principal names that end with `@sec213.com`:

```psh
$domain = ([adsi]'').distinguishedName
$ou     = "OU=users,OU=SEC213,OU=Uofguelph,$domain"
$suffix = '@sec213.com'

Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -like '*$suffix'" -SearchBase $ou
```

Comment: Hey Ansgar, one last thing. How do I send the output of that to an email?.. I've been trying to send it the HTML formatting way with no luck :(.. I keep receiving this error: Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.3.2 Service not 
available"

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your original code is just missing a wildcard. This method worked great for me:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -Like "account*"}
```

That or if you're searching for the domain:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -Like "*@domain.com"}
```

I know this is way late to the came, but I came across this while searching and wanted to input a simple solution when searching the entire domain.